# iPhone app: navigate to tab bar scenario

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with a maybe-strange navigation scenario. I'll try to explain:

> 1) first scene: select an available item from a list
>
> > 1.1) once selected, you navigate to a tab view allowing you to view/edit the various attributes
>
> 2) if the desired item isn't available, you may create a new one (by selecting a "+" bar button) which navigates to an alternate scene
>
> > 2.1) there may be multiple scenes required to create the item, all scenes are simply pushed on the stack to allow the user to go back, select different options, etc.
> >
> > 2.2) once all scenes have been displayed and all attributes have been collected, the new "item" will be created and saved.
> >
> > 2.3) now, I want to automatically act as though the user selected this item from the beginning, that is, I want to pop all previous views off the stack and navigate directly into the tabs (step 1.1).

Does this make sense? Easy to do? Is there a better way to go about this? I'm using xCode 4.2 with storyboards.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want (+) button on TabBar you should subclass UITabBar: Fo ex. TabBarPlus and set this class in storyboard.

But easier place (+) button on navigation bar.

The max number of displaying tabsart is 5 for iphone and 8 for ipad. If the there > number of tabs the last is "More" tab thet displaing list of other tubs in tableview. I you want displaying more tabs on tabbar then you should subclass UITabBar :)

If you want by back button on naigation bar switching beetwing Views that references with TabBar buttons you must create stack in code and hide backbutton of navigationbar and use castom left button of navigationbar.

The other navigation can be easy done in storyboard